# Trying to implement cas linkedlist

Tags: c++, multithreading, linked-list, compare-and-swap

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;

    Node(int i)
    {
        data = i;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

class List
{
public:
    List()
    {
        headptr = 0L;
    }

    long long headptr;
    long long count = 1;

    void push(Node* newnode)
    {
    while (true)
    {
        long long tmph = headptr;
        long long tmp = (tmph<<12) >> 12; //untag
        newnode->next = (Node*)tmp;
        long long cnt = (count++) << 52;
        long long tagnew = (long long)newnode | cnt;
        newnode = (Node*)tagnew;
        if (_InterlockedCompareExchange64((volatile long long*)&headptr, tagnew, tmph) == tmph)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

     Node* pop()
     {
          while (true)
          {
              long long headp = headptr;
              long long untagheadp = (headp << 12) >> 12; //untag;
              Node* headnode = (Node*)untagheadp;
              long long nextp = (long long)headnode->next;
              if (headp == NULL)
                  return NULL;
              long long cnt = (long long)(count++) << 52;
              nextp = nextp | cnt;
              if (_InterlockedCompareExchange64((volatile long long*)&headptr, nextp, headp))
              { 
                  return headnode;

               }

       };

static List* freelist = new List();
static List* headlist = new List();

void threadbody()
{
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 10000)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            if (freelist->headptr != NULL)
            {
                Node* temp = freelist->pop();
                headlist->push(temp);
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            if (headlist->headptr != NULL)
            {
                Node* temp = headlist->pop();
                freelist->push(temp);
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
    std::cout << "Thread End" << std::endl;
}
int main()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        freelist->push(new Node(i));
    }

    freelist->showcount();
    std::thread t1(&threadbody);

    int count = 0;
    while (count < 10000)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            if (freelist->headptr != NULL)
            {
                Node* temp = freelist->pop();
                headlist->push(temp);
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            if (headlist->headptr != NULL)
            {
                Node* temp = headlist->pop();
                freelist->push(temp);
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
    std::cout << "Main End" << std::endl;
    t1.join();
    freelist->showcount();
    headlist->showcount();
}
```

I'm trying to implement linkedlist using cas.
I implement using tag. first 12bit is tag and 52bit is address(x64)
push and pop works fine when I run main thread only.
But, It doesn't work with 2 thread.
Running through code, what I find is a Node->next points its own.
Can't figure how to solve this problem.
Give an idea would be a pleasure.

Comment: What is the cas linked list?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow this is essentially a lock-free stack (in particular the [Treiber stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treiber_stack))

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, the problem is that `getAddress` has two accesses to the pointer it is passed.

When you call `getAddress(&headptr);`, there is a read of `headptr` (thru the `ptr` parameter of `getAddress`.  Several statements later there is a write to `headptr`.  In between that read and that write, the other thread can have a successful `_InterlockedCompareExchange64` which changes the value of `headptr`.  When that happens the write of `*ptr = temp;` will change the value stored by the previous thread.

The "cheap" fix is to have `getAddress` also do an interlocked exchange when writing to `ptr`.  However, why does `getAddress` write back to `*ptr` at all? This seems unnecessary has you lose your tag information stored there.

Unrelated, the call to `build` in `pop` does nothing as you are ignoring the returned value.

And there is much Undefined Behavior in your code, since you assume that only the lower 52 bits of an address are used.  Things like `reinterpret_cast<Node*>(newptr);` can create bad pointers since the non-pointer `newptr` is a computed value and not the result of a cast from a pointer.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering.     I change a code little bit. not using reinterpret_cast.    When I run this program, I get a read access violation.    Do you know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `counter` variable. You use non-atomic increments on that variable to calculate the new tag, but this is wrong. You cannot use a separate variable, but you have to use the tag that is embedded in your `headptr`. The update of the tag and the update of the pointer to the next item must happen in a *single atomic operation*. Also, you should consider using C++11 atomics.

As a reference, you can take a look at my implementation of a lock-free stack in this gist: https://gist.github.com/mpoeter/926a80eda0c2c2dce8424b1175a24c84